# React Multiple Higher-Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just discovering the amazing benefits of using HOC in my react projects.

My question is there any performance hit for calling multiple HOC functions on a component?

**Example**

```
export default withState(withLabel(withTheme(MyComponent)))
```

This will of course only `render` one component, however looking at my react dev tools i can see the outputted HOC components three levels deep. Is this something to be wary of or is there a better approach to calling multiple HOC on a component?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

*I wouldn't use that.* It's complicated to understand where the props come from, when you are looking at your `MyComponent` component. There are much more downsides using this pattern. Anyway if you decided to use `HOC`s use it in a right way e.g.

```
const withDetails = Component => {
  const C = props => {
    // do something
  }

  // assign display & wrapped names - easier to debug
  C.displayName = `withRouter(${Component.displayName))`
  C.WrappedComponent = Component;

  return C;
}
```

Instead of using `HOC`s i suggest looking at `render props` react pattern. It's well explained in a [`Use a Render Prop!`](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce) article by Michael Jackson (react-router creator).

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: FWIW I've had much more difficult times hunting down problems in components using render props than any HOC.

Answer (score 9):

Your syntax is equivalent to doing:

```
<StateProvider>
  <LabelProvider>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </LabelProvider>
</StateProvider>
```

The performance hit will come from how these HOC are implemented. You would probably have to look at each of them.

Example:

- Theme Provider HOCs usually store a bunch of colors and variables in the React context. So using only one at the very root of your App is enough.
- One could imagine that your LabelProvider simply adds an extra span before your component, in which case there is little to worry about
- StateProviders like redux usually inject props in the component just below them so you don't really have a choice but to use them whenever you need state objects.

In conclusion, there are no hard rules. Your main focus should be on understanding what these HOC do and to try to limit unnecessary re-renders of your app.